# Using schtasks.exe, how do I create a Scheduled Task, then delete it afterwards?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-task-scheduler

I have a `.bat` file which needs to schedule a command at 5:00 PM.

I cannot use Task Scheduler, because at the end of the file I need to delete the scheduled command (cancel it), without having to manually confirm the delete!

I need an alternative to the `at` command, since its deprecated.

Right now I'm doing it like this, but it needs user input when deleting it!

```
SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC DAILY /TN "Custom\Abort shutdown task" /TR "%windir%\System32\shutdown.exe /a" /ST 17:00:30
SCHTASKS /delete /TN "Custom\Abort shutdown task"
```

Answer (score 2):

Check `schtasks.exe /CREATE /?` for this:

```
/Z          Marks the task for deletion after its final run.
```

In top of that, there's the `/SC` switch, giving you the possibility to launch the task only once.

The combination might be what you are looking for.

Comment: So does the task self delete?

Comment: Indeed: the amount of times that it is run, is defined by `/SC`. If you set this to `Once`, then the first run automatically is the final run, and then the `/Z` switch deletes the task after its (final) run.